# How to place AdView at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have some problem in placing `AdView` at the bottom, if I add this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adview_preview_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></LinearLayout>
```

`AdView` code at the bottom, it will either overlap or come to the top of screen.

Kindly help me in running this `AdView` at bottom. Here is the complete code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#585858" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/serviceName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


  <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

          <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adview_preview_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></LinearLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `TabHost`:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/adview_preview_layout"
```

Like this:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adview_preview_layout"  /// add this line
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip" />
```